# LowerCase Like statement in Lift Mapper

Tags: scala, lift

It is possible to set query to compare all records in table in lowercase?

Example:
I want to build query:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE LOWER(item.title) LIKE (%abc%)
```

but with Like object in Mapper i can't say that item.title has to be lowerCase.

```
Like(Item.title, "%" + searchText.toLowerCase + "%")
```

Simply - user inserts ABC into search field and i want to view him in results item aBc also.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found right solution:

to complete all my findings - here are all right solutions for future generation ;)

```
Cmp(Item.title, OprEnum.Like, Full("%abc%"), None, Full("LOWER"))
```

or

```
BySql[Item]("lower(title) LIKE ?", IHaveValidatedThisSQL("Kajo", "101129"), "%aBc%".toLowerCase)
```